# About VTK and ThreeJs develop

Tags: three.js, vtk

I want to do a VTK + Three.js development project, mainly to use the streamline function part of VTK, but I don’t know what the feasibility is, do you have any experience in this area？Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`three.js` provides a `VTKLoader` which can be used to import `VTK` assets into a scene. There is also an official example demonstrating the basic usage:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_vtk

However, the loader only supports a subset of the VTK standard. For example VTK supports five different dataset formats: structured points, structured grid, rectilinear grid, unstructured grid, and polygonal data. VTKLoader can only process the last one (POLYDATA) right now. Depending on your project requirements, you have to enhance the loader by yourself.

`three.js R112`

Comment: Could you tell me，how to enhance the loader？thank you

Comment: Sorry, but this is something which depends on your project requirements. You have to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: Because VTK has a JS version, but I don’t know the JS version can meet my needs for drawing streamlines, so this question was raised, thank you for your reception.